# Django html issuce unable to click hyperlink

Tags: python, html, django, directory, hyperlink

i created a Djange, There are .html file in my templates. i just dont know why when clink this link the website no any respone. But if i open this html without django the link is work
`<a href="file://\\HKCT-OFFS-01\Data\Information Technology\Documents\Contract">useful link </a>`
anyone have any idea? T^T

`<a href="https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/hong-kong/hong-kong">website</a>`
i tried this is work
`<a href="file://\\HKCT-OFFS-01\Data\Information Technology\Documents\Contract">useful link </a>`
but fail to open share folder

FYI`\\HKCT-OFFS-01\Data\Information Technology\Documents\Contract`
This is a workable path.

Comment: can you provide more details about what are you trying to do if you can please provide the code ( `urls.py`, `views.py` and the HTML template).

Answer (score 0):

your url path is invalid use the followin

```html
<a href="https://yourpath"></a>
```

If you are trying to share a directory/folder path as a resource from django it is not possible to do that.
Take note the following:

1. Django has a built-in `{% url '<your path>' %}` template tag for dynamically passing URLs in the template based on the URLs in your django app
2. If you are passing external URLs which are not part of your django project, take note of the path (URL) it must be right.
3. Paths in Windows and Linux OS are different I would encourage you to use the Linux format because you will deploy your app to a Linux server.

Comment: No, I can access "file://\\HKCT-OFFS-01\Data\Information Technology\Documents\Contract" or "\\HKCT-OFFS-01\Data\Information Technology\Documents\Contract".

Comment: It's just a share folder path.